# Determine type of website from URL (blog vs. forum vs. resources etc)

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I've been searching for this for hours, and can't seem to find anything remotely close to it. Maybe, I don't have the right search queries, so I thought I would ask here:

**Situation**
I have a list of about a thousand URLs in a mySQL DB that are all mixed types of sites (blog/article, forum, resources page, directory etc). I would like to take these URLs and determine what kind of site it is without visiting every single site. Is there a way that this can be done?

The only possible solution I can think of is to search for common URL structures like /forums, /blog or the subdomains and filter that way. The problem with this is that I will be missing a lot of other potentials and will have to manually go through them.

Does anyone have any creative ideas or possibly a resource/script that can provide more information on this?

Comment: Well lets think, if you had to do it manually, what would you look for?

Comment: Are you just trying to extract "type" and tag the page via that?

Comment: @castis I would have probably set it up in an iframe and store types in a DB to filter through it quicker, but it still takes too much time.

Comment: @MadsBjaerge I'm looking for the "type of website" (ie. blog, article, resources page, directory, forum etc.)  I would take one of these "types" and store the value in mysql with its corresponding row.

Comment: @user1701252 Can you glean this information via url alone?

Comment: @castis Thank you for bringing this to light. I realized from Xeschylus' comment that I will probably have to do a file_get_contents() to further filter down beyond removing anything from typical paramters like forum.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

First search the URL for keywords as you mentioned.

Next if none are found, follow up with a site search using something like [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) or a regex on the contents of the page which you get get easily with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).  That may get some false positives, if a blog mentions a forum, likely you would just search on a set of keywords and the first result would be the one to go with.  You might be able to get a little more information out of the content, but it would quickly get complicated.

One example of more complicated, search for admin interface based on the base url, such as wordpress being www.example.com/wp-admin.

Comment: Great point. I'm not strong on regex, so I'd have to go looking for some tutorials on this again. I think the false positives will be a little too high on this, but I'll hit the drawing board again and try to better map out the process. Thanks for the input.